# Movieclip names

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm having troubles with AS3 and addChild methods.

First, I create an object called "container". Inside container I create an empty object with an empty MovieClip from library called "holder". Then I create the Movieclips inside the container.holder
But I cannot access to the MovieClips! Anyone knows why? Here is the code:

```
// Creating object
var container:Object {
   x: 30,
   y: 30
}

// Empty object
var eObject: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
container.holder = eObject;

// Creating Movieclips
var mc : MovieClip;
   for (var i : int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var mc: _myClip = new _myClip(); // _myClip is a MC from my library.
      mc.name = "myMc"+ i;
      mc.x = 10;
      container.holder.addChild(mc);
}

// Calling MovieClips
container.holder["myMc"+3].x = 40; // Nothing happens
```

Comment: container must have "holder" property like x and y?

Comment: What I need is call container.holder[myMC3], like un as2: container.holder.attachMovie(mc, "myMC"+i, 0);

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What's the point to have a MovieClip inside an Object ? Should it be a MovieClip as well ? What is supposed to happen when you try to set the x property of your Movieclip - the movieclip is not even visible because it is just inside an object.

Comment: I am doing the TonyPA tile tutorial in as2 to as3. He creates the game object. Then, inside game object he creates the 'clip' and add an empty mc to hold tiles and the character. In as2 he attach the tiles using: game.clip.attachMovie("tiles_mc", "t_"+i+"_"+j", 1);

Comment: Then he can edit the tiles calling game.clip[name] (name will be t_i_j), what I need is this but in AS3.

Comment: I see but what's the point of using an Object and a holder here ? Basically you add the MovieClips to this holder and then want to get them out of the holder and attach them to stage ? Why don't you attach them right from the library? I think you can't access your movieclips like that unless your holder MovieClip is added to the stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the complexity and needless usage of the `name` property by using an Array:

```
var items:Array = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var mc:_myClip = new _myClip();

    container.holder.addChild(mc);
    items.push(mc);
}

items[2].x = 40;
```

Comment: Or a Vector :
    var items:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();

but I really don't understand the meaning / use, of the "container" here, the x and y properties and a list of MovieClip...
Items in container may be whatever the user wants without throwing compile time Errors (is this really what you want?).
You should totally forget about AS2...
and var container:Object {
   x: 30,
   y: 30
}
will throw and Error in strict mode...